# Fix corrupt /bin/sh link

Tags: shell, ssh, system-recovery, synology

I used to access it via SSH but I wanted to connect to it with *zsh* instead of *bash*.

I made a mistake with my *Synology* NAS:

I deleted the `/bin/sh` symbolic link to `/bin/bash` to replace it with `/bin/zsh` but since then I cannot connect to it using SSH:

```
$ ssh synology.local
martin@synology.local's password:
/bin/sh: No such file or directory
Connection to synology.local closed.
```

I have no idea how I can fix that...

Comment: You'd probably have more luck on a Synology forum. Recovery using ssh and the martin account there is now out of the question. You'd need another way to get in there and fix the link. Hard to tell without knowing that product.

Comment: You can try `ssh synology.local /bin/bash` - this maybe bypasses the login shell. See ssh manpage: _If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell_.

Comment: Does `sftp` work to the Synology? If so I'll write up an answer

Comment: @ridgy No it still do the error

Comment: @roaima I don't think but I restored the whole system so I won't be able to try your sftp solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @ridgy No, it is impossible to bypass the login shell with SSH, by design.

Comment: Tip: have a fallback account with a different shell (preferably statically linked) where you keep the default configuration.

Comment: @Gilles You are right. I was mistaken by the manpage and differences in login - but without a valid shell, login isn't possible. Thank you.

Comment: @Gilles Good idea for the next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to restore my Synology software without losing the data thanks to [this Synology Knowledgebase article](https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/General/How_to_reset_your_Synology_NAS). It explains how to factory reset the configuration and operating system:

- Use a paperclip to press the reset button on the back of the device and hold it for 4 seconds until it beeps. (This resets the configuration).
- Release the button.
- Within the next 10 seconds, hold the button for 4 seconds again until it beeps. (This resets the OS).
- Release the button again.
- Open Synology Assistant and check that the NAS now says "Not Configured".
- Double click the NAS to reinstall the OS.

Answer (score 0):

It can connect to the NAS using telnet.
Repair your changed files.
Then you can enter ssh again.
Like me that changed the sshd_config, changed it back, and restarted ssh using DSM.

please forgive my bad english.

Comment: Can you provide more detailed instructions?  What does “Repair your changed files.” mean?  How does `/bin/sh` get fixed? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.